# Update input state with function

Tags: reactjs

I am experimenting with react right now and I am trying to understand how batching work. As I understand it, when I use function in setState, it reads the current state reliably. I defined an input tag and I can update the Input text when it accepts object as the following:

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
<input
    onChange={(e) => {
      setInputText(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
```

However, when I tried to update state with function as the following:

```
<input
    onChange={(e) => {
      setInputText((inputText) => e.target.value);
    }}
  />
```

for second onchange event trigger, it throws "Cannot read property 'value' of null". Why is that?

Comment: For future reference, calling e.persist() before setInputText persists the event before garbage collected so the above can work as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Events are [pooled](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). And the `setState` callback is async. So when you extract the value the event is already back in pool.

```
<input
    onChange={(e) => {
      const {value} = e.target;
      setInputText((inputText) => value);
    }}
  />
```

BTW you don't really need the callback version of set state in this example because next value does not depend on the previous one.

Comment: Yes, your are right I do not need callback here. I am just experimenting with react and realized it is not working with events. Thanks for quick response!

Comment: NP. Glad I could help.